# Laravel query builder orderBy not ordering

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a project that uses the [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) and I am running in to trouble when trying to order the data. First, I need to order by name which is a joined column from the 'users' table.

My code:

```
        $Records = Tickets::with('User', 'Session', 'Session.Course');
        $Records = $Records->orderBy('first_name', 'desc'); //generates an error as no first_name column exists in the current query, although the first name is rendered in the view!
        $Records = $Records->get();
```

I am not sure how the query builder is making the association to fetch the user names, as calling toSql() to get the raw query doesn't generate a join query at any point.

What is the proper way to do this?

This has been really tricky and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show us your code before `$Records->orderBy('grade', 'desc');`?

Comment: Sure, please see edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) doesn't add JOINs to the query, it executes a separate query for each relationship.

You can add a [JOIN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) yourself:

```php
$Records = Tickets::select('tickets.*')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tickets.user_id')
    ->orderBy('users.first_name', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

In Laravel 5.2.32 you can reuse the relationship with a modified `withCount()`:

```php
$Records = Tickets::withCount(['User as first_name' => function($query) {
    $query->select('first_name');
}])->orderBy('first_name', 'desc')->get();
```

This selects `users.first_name` with a subquery:

```php
select `tickets`.*,
  (select `first_name`
   from `users`
   where `tickets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) as `first_name`
from `tickets`
order by `first_name` desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is helpful. What if I need to create a 'click to sort' functionality and almost all columns from the join need to be sortable?

Comment: Can a query be ordered by multiple columns at the same time?

Comment: No, only one at a time.

Comment: You can replace `'first_name'` with a variable `$column`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Generating the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withCount()`

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: I am using illuminate/database as a standalone composer package within a symfony project and I'm on version v5.2.28 of the database package..

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$Records = Tickets::select('tickets.*')
    ->join('users', 'tickets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('users.first_name', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually worked beautifully! For some reason not passing '=' as an argument to the join function doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning which table has `first_name` column so you have to define the table name.
Try this one:

```
$Records->orderBy('users.first_name', 'desc');
```